# Cannot install pip3.5. Pip is configured with locations that require TSL/SSL?

Tags: raspbian, python, pip

I'm trying to install pip3.5 with python3.5 on raspbian on my raspberry pi, and I can not get it to work for the life of me. I have already installed python 3.5 without problems but I cannot seem to run get-pip.py.
To get pip I did `wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py`
and when I try to run it with `sudo python3.5 get-pip.py` I get an error saying "Pip is configured with locations that require TSL/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available. 
I've tried every solution I can find but nothing seems to work. If its helpful in anyway my pi currently has Python 2.7, 3, and 3.4. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you tried googling your error message to see if anyone else has had a similar issue?